# PyCharm external tool parameter

Tags: pycharm

I want to run a script before running a python script. So I added the script `pyuic5` with the parameter `~/folder/test.ui` in "Run/Debug Configurations" - "Before launch: External tool".

When I run the script, the console shows the command `pyuic5 ~/folder/test.ui` like expected, but followed with an error message from `pyuic5`:

```
Error: No such file or directory: "~/folder/test.ui"
```

The file exists though, when I copy the command into a terminal, it works perfectly. Does PyCharm edit the command somehow?

#### edit:

I have the same problem with other commands also:

E.g. the command `sh` with the parameter `test.sh` prints:

```
sh: 0: Can't open test.sh
```

Comment: Do you have set pyuic5 in your environment variables, if you are using windows?

Comment: @Rotan075 PyCharm recognizes `pyuic5`, because the error message is generated from `pyuic5`. But it somehow doesn't recognize the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Program" TextBox, inside the Edit Tool of PyCharm, you should specify not only the name of the program you are using, but also the absolute path to it.
Also, make sure to specify the Parameters and the Working Dir correctly.

---

### Solution/example if you are using Linux:

1. Open a new Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)
2. Run `which pyuic5`
3. Copy the output of the command above (example, "/usr/progtools/anaconda2/bin/pyuic5")
4. Paste the copied output (without quotes) in the "Program" TextBox of Edit Tool (in PyCharm).
5. Set up the "Parameters" properly (example "-o form_mainWindow.py mainwindow.ui"
6. If the mainwindow.ui file is in your Project Working Directory, in "Working Directory" copy and paste "$ProjectFileDir$" (without quotes)
7. Click all Ok's and Apply's, and Build/Run the project!

---

**PS**: Remember to always save the file when editing the UI in Qt prior to re-building the project in PyCharm!!